# Use Class in plugin vendor folder [CakePHP 3.X]

Tags: php, api, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to use a function in Cake\Component\Component in a plugin in the vendor file, but for some reason (I think because of the namespace) it won't recognized the function (undefined) even though I put `use Cake\Component\Component;` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: One thing is putting `use` statement to the file, the second is that the file with the `Cake\Component\Component` class needs to be `include`d - either by `include`/`require` statement or through some kind of class loader.

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. Try to add details so that someone who has no idea about your code, would be able to reproduce the problem. Like, what exactly happens? What exactly should happen instead? What code exactly are you trying to use, where and in what way exactly?